# Remove all between two exact expressions in excel

Tags: excel, replace, find, opencart, formula

Im trying to do something with my opencart store, i want to remove wrong formatting from all product descriptions, so i made one export in excel of all my products and descriptions ( products are near 8000) and i want to do this io this is my exported description in one cell in excel:

<span style="font-weight: bold; color: rgb(37, 37, 37); font-family: &quot;Myriad Pro&quot;, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">Единичен апликатор, с който лесно се нанасят сенките за очи.</span>

i want to delete everything between

> style="font-weight: bold;

and

> ">

(because i need to use onlu bolded words to stay)
Can i use some formula in excel to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: i want just the bold styled words to stay, so i must search text between two expressions (ex. style=&quot; font-weight: bold; AND &quot;) everything between this two must go away

Answer (score 0):

If your text is in cell `A1` use the below formula,

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("font-weight: bold",A1)+17)&MID(A1,FIND(""">",A1),LEN(A1))
```

[image]

The formula searches for the text `font-weight: bold` in the cell `A1` and strips the left most part till the text. The next part is finding the `">` and stripping the character after that. The `&` is to concatenate both

Comment: @ДобромирМилчев  Added the explanation to the answer

Comment: Yes im getting "Error in value"

Comment: @ДобромирМилчев Looks like your delimiter should be `;` instead of commas `,`